# change email address that is being used in server

Tags: php, mysql, email

i'm setting up a system that whenever a user registers on my site it will automatically send a confirmation email. 
My problem is that the email that is using ends with info@buick.websitewelcome.com which is weird because my website is not buick.websitewelcome.com. 
My expected email should be info@myaddress.info.


How would I do that, i'm using CPanel FYI.

This is also my code when sending the confirmation address

```
    function SendUserEmailVerificationCode( $code,$username,$email_address ) {

            // multiple recipients
            $to  = $email_address;

            // subject
            $subject = 'Verification Code';

            // message
            $message = "
                    Dear ".$username."<br><br>
                    You received this email because you registered at http://myaddress.info/.<br>
                    To complete registration please enter this registration code<h1>".$code."</h1></strong> on the link below:<br>
                    http://myaddress.info/verifyMe.php?username=".$username."
                    ";
            $headers = 'From: info@myaddress.info' . "\r\n";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

            // Mail it
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Comment: I would talk to your hosting provider if the email is not properly set.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `cron` (or a background) script running on the server? If so you can just put the message in a queue and can do some funky stuff like giving an instance response, retrying on failure.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command line paramter -f as shown on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3048

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

-f will set the From address, -r will override the default Return-path that sendmail generates (typically the From address gets used).

Ref: [PHP Manual: mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#94170)

Answer (score 1):

The fourth argument in the `mail()` function is used for headers as you have already noticed. Just add a `From` header. This will change the from field.

```
$headers .= 'From: info@mywebaddress.com'."\r\n";
```

Additionally, if you also want to change the *envelope mail from* (which you probably want), you can use the fifth argument. This is used for options that should be passed directly to `sendmail`. Here, you should add `-f info@mywebaddress.com`. A simple example is shown below.

```
mail('recipient@domain.com', 'Subject', 'Message',
  'From: info@myaddress.info','-f info@myaddress.info');
```

And also, all of this is mentioned in [the official PHP manual on `mail()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).